# Cloning list items using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, for-loop

New to JQuery, so please go easy :). I want to add a new list item each time the for statement is completed. In this instance the for statement runs three times, so the list item should be cloned three times. Can someone please assist?

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" >

var myStringArray = ["ID1", "ID2", "ID3"]
$(function () {

    var children = $("#imageList").children().clone();

    for (string in myStringArray)
    {
        $("#imageList").prepend(children);

        alert(string[0])
        console.log(string[0])
    }     
});

</script>


<ul id="imageList">
<!-- List of scrolling images -->
    <li id="image1" class="ImagesScroller" >

    </li>  
</ul>
```

The ideal output for this would be the following:

```
* ID1
* ID2
* ID3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make a new clone in each iteration, else you will be simply moving the same copy again and again.

```js
var myStringArray = ["ID1", "ID2", "ID3"]
$(function() {

  $.each(myStringArray, function(i, string) {
    var children = $("#imageList").children().first().clone();
    children.text(string).removeAttr('id');//since id of an elemnet must be unique
    $("#imageList").prepend(children);
    console.log(string[0])
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="imageList">
  <!-- List of scrolling images -->
  <li id="image1" class="ImagesScroller">

  </li>
</ul>
```

---

You can do by creating the elements using script instead of cloning like

```js
var myStringArray = ["ID1", "ID2", "ID3"]
$(function() {

  $.each(myStringArray, function(i, string) {
    $('<li />', {
      text: string,
      'class': 'ImagesScroller'
    }).appendTo('#imageList')
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="imageList">
</ul>
```

Comment: Excellent - Thanks Arun!

Answer (score 0):

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" >

var myStringArray = ["ID1", "ID2", "ID3"]
$(function () {
    $.each(myStringArray, function(index, item){
    $("#imageList").append('<li id="image'+index+'" class="imageScroller">'+item'+</li>');
})

});
```

```
<ul id="imageList">
<!-- List of scrolling images -->
</ul>
```